# Intent without second activity name

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, action

I know that `intents` are used to to start a new activity from another one, and pass data from activity to another. But in the documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html there are also constructors of Intent to which we only pass an `action` (no parameter of a second activity class), so I was wondering in which case this kind of `intent` can be used ?

Comment: Read up on [implicit](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#ExampleSend) vs [explicit](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#ExampleExplicit) intents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Intent provides a facility for performing late runtime binding between the code in different applications.

[**`Intent`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Two Primary form of Intents **implicit** and **explicit**

You are Talking about implicit Intents

> **Implicit Intents** have not specified a component; instead, they must include enough information for the system to determine which of the available components is best to run for that intent.

Suppose if Your app need to ask the User to enable **GPS** in his mobile for finding his Latitude and Longitude co-ordinates.In that Case We need to navigate him to **GPS** Settings automatically

Here is the example to move to the GPS(Launch Settings) of the phone

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
 startActivity(intent);
```